# Extjs listener on keystroke checking if its ANY character

Tags: javascript, extjs

I cant seem to find this anywhere. I want to find the best way to check whether a keystroke is actually a character.

```
listeners:{
    'keyup':function(f, e){
        //Is key a letter/character
    }
}
```

EDIT

Thanks to everyone who has answered, I DO know how to detect the actual key that was pressed, I want to know how to detect whether the key is actually a character (not arrows, backspace, enter etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to capture the parameters that are sent to the event. Then evaluate the `event.getKey()`:

```
listeners:{
    'keyup':function(field, event){
        if(event.getKey() >= 65 && event.getKey() <= 90) {
           //the key was A-Z
        }
        if(event.getKey() >= 97 && event.getKey() <= 122) {
           //the key was a-z
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to use those methods (updated question with parameters) but I wasnt sure how to check if its any characters without having to loop through...

Comment: I updated my answer. There is no need to perform a loop - you can just perform a range compare as described above.

Answer (score 6):

To capture keyboard events you must set the `enableKeyEvents` property on the component to `true`.

```
...,
enableKeyEvents: true,
listeners:{
    'keyup': function(f, e){
        var charCode = e.getCharCode();
        var key      = e.getKey();
    }
},
...
```

See "[Detecting keystrokes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)" for a description of the difference between **keyCode** and **charCode**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am able to get the key and charcode, but I want to check if its a character, any character...

Comment: You can't (reliably) get information about the typed character from a `keyup` or `keydown` event. It has to be `keypress`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have the correct parameters for your event.

```
'keyup': {
        fn: function(field,event) {
         //use event.getKey() to get the key
         }
    }
```

The first parameter is the field (form element) and second is the event object. You can make use of the event object to get your key press details. Use the `getKey()` method or `getCharCode()` as per your requirement.

`getKey` method returns the numeric code. You will have to compare the range (a=65 & z=90) to check if the keypress was character. Ext JS provides some static variables for checking special keys.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell from the `keyup` or `keydown` events whether the keystroke produced a character or not. The only event that can do this is `keypress`. Even then, it's quite tricky to detect in some browsers because of inconsistent behaviour. See section "3.2. Values Returned on Character Events" on the following page: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html